# DBD::mysql error in ActivePerl 5.28 on Windws10 64bits, Can't load mysql.dll

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, activeperl, dbd

I'm having an issue with the DBD::mysql module.  This question has been asked before on this forum but a solution was not posted so I thought I would repost it.  Sorry if this is not appropriate for this forum.  This is my first post.

You can find the original post from bLIGU here:

[Error using perl module DBD::mysql in ActivePerl 5.28 on Windws10 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521072/error-using-perl-module-dbdmysql-in-activeperl-5-28-on-windws10-64bits)

I have the exact same problem.  I'm just upgrading my Active Perl version.  Nothing else changed.  I'm running the same MySql server version and this script ran fine before the update and it runs fine if I go back to version 5.20.2.2002 and use PPM to download the packages.

Note that ActiveState now requires you to build a custom version of ActivePerl with the modules online and generates an install file for you.  PPM is no longer supported.

Here's the error:

```
    install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load 'C:/Perl64/site/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
  at (eval 11) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 11) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at C:\E22_TE~1\ICTDEV~1\Scripts\UPDATE~1.PL line 136.strong text
```

The file C:/Perl64/site/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll is present so I'm wondering if the DLL is trying to load something else and returns an error.

Comment: The path given in the error is different to the path that you say exists (one contains an extra `/site/` which the other is missing. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Dave Cross: Yes it's a typo.  Thanks for pointing it out.  The path does exist.  I fixed it in the original post.

Comment: @NedLeBouthillier According to the [release notes](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.30.2.1-64bit.html) for Strawberry Perl `DBD::mysql` comes preinstalled. Maybe you could try Strawberry Perl?

Comment: Re "*The file [mysql.dll] is present*", Loading a DLL often requires loading other DLLs too (e.g. the mysql library). That's presumably the one that can't be loaded.